# Is it possible to groupBy a column that is not the key and append the aggregated results to the original record in Apache Flink/Beam

Tags: python, apache-flink, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, flink-streaming

Let’s say I have data as following…

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | ABC | 101 | 1 |
| B | ABC | 102 | 1 |
| C | ABCD | 101 | 1 |
| D | ABCD | 101 | 1 |
| E | ABC | 101 | 1 |

I would like groupBy `Col2` and `Col3` and sum(or any other complex operation) of `Col4` independently and storing the aggregates back as following...
For simplicity, I've kept col4 as 1 so that count and the frequency are the same.

| Col1 | Col2 | Col2Agg | Col3 | Col3Agg | Col4 | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | ABC | (ABC,1) | 101 | (101,1) | 1 | Seeing ABC, 101 for the first time |
| B | ABC | (ABC,2) | 102 | (102,1) | 1 | Have already seen ABC once, 102 for the first time |
| C | ABCD | (ABCD,1) | 101 | (101,2) | 1 | Have seen ABCD once and 101 twice |
| D | ABCD | (ABCD,2) | 101 | (101,3) | 1 | Have seen ABCD twice and 101 thrice |
| E | ABC | (ABC,3) | 101 | (101,4) | 1 | Have seen ABC thrice and 101 four times |

I am exploring if such a logic can be implemented in apache beam. I am planning on persisting the `Col2Agg` and `Col3Agg` as states so that when I restart the system, the count isn't lost. I would also like to keep the number of records consistent with the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. The feature of Beam that is the best fit for this use case is "stateful DoFn" also called "stateful ParDo".

The official documentation is at https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#state-and-timers and the introductory blog post is https://beam.apache.org/blog/stateful-processing/ and it uses an example just like what you are talking about.

There is an important caveat: Beam is designed for massively parallel computation. Parallelism and ordering are exact opposites. So if you are wanting to get the elements in a particular order, you will quickly hit scalability and cost limitations. But if you simply want to attach a count of "what you've seen" to each element, stateful DoFn will work perfectly.

Comment: Thank you. Ordering is not important. I should have mentioned that in the above case data should be seen as time series data from top to bottom. I've read through that post and seems like it would work. I do not have a proper environment to test this with high parallelism.

So I have 3 questions...

Comment: 1. How does Beam maintain the consistency of the state across multiple executors in `stateful DoFn`? I ask this because I was under the opinion that beam does this efficiently with the help of groupByKey/CombinePerKey where data corresponding to one key (or few keys) go to one executor for efficient aggregations.
2. Can I save these states to a long-term storage (like hdfs, google bigtable)?

Comment: 3. If so, can I aggregate these states in the following pattern (with respect to time)?
Do aggregate over 1 minute -> save to hdfs -> Sum up last 5 to get 5 minute aggregates -> save to hdfs -> Sum up last 3/4 to get 15/20 minute aggregates -> Save to hdfs -> Sum up to 1 hr aggregates -> Save to hdfs -> Sum up to a day -> save to hdfs.

Comment: I think these might be great top-level questions to post here or to a Beam user list or slack channel.